# i can't pull the id part in the database

Tags: php, post, get

I'm a bit new in php, and when I applied the codes in a video tutorial, I saw an error like this
I can't pull the "id" part when deleting the data from the following database.

my code;

```
function introsil($vt){

    $introid=$_GET["id"];

    $verial=self::sorgum($vt,"select * from intro where id=$introid",1);

    echo'<div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12">';

    //delete docs
    unlink("../".$verial["resimyol"]);


    // delete my database
    self::sorgum($vt,"delete from intro where id=$introid",0);


    echo'<div class="alert alert-success mt-5 font-weight-bold">Docs delete success.<i class="ti-alert ml-2"></i></div>';

    echo'</div></div>';
}
```

my ""sorgum"" functions is here;

```
function sorgum($vt,$sorgu,$tercih=0){
    $al=$vt->prepare($sorgu);
    $al->execute();

    if($tercih==1):
        return $al->fetch();

    elseif ($tercih==2):
        return $al;

    endif;

}
```

[my error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlvgM.png)

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/DYnjBz.png ı<<< have a "id"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the security side of me needs to let you know that if you are going to use `$_GET['id']` to enter directly in to a query, you **need** to sanitize and escape it otherwise, you will be subject to an [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

In regards to retrieving the ID, I would be inclined to advise that you submit it to the function:

```
function introsil($vt, $id){

    $introid = $id;

    $verial = self::sorgum($vt,"select * from intro where id=$introid",1);

    echo '<div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12">';

    //delete docs
    unlink("../".$verial["resimyol"]);


    // delete my database
    self::sorgum($vt,"delete from intro where id=$introid",0);


    echo '<div class="alert alert-success mt-5 font-weight-bold">Docs delete success.<i class="ti-alert ml-2"></i></div>';

    echo '</div></div>';
}
```

This can be then called like so:

```
<?php
    introsil($vt,  $_GET['id']);
```

I have not sanitized or escaped the `$id` variable in my examples. I recommend you check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for information on how to safely do this.